# Open XML, modify and save again

Tags: powershell

I have a build script to modify some Nuget *.nuspec dependency versions which used to work - but somehow it doesn't anymore. I do not know if its because of my updating to Windows 10 or the Powershell versions changed.

```
Function ChangeNugetSpecDependencyVersion() {

    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$filePath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$packageId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$publishVersion
    )

    [xml] $toFile = (Get-Content $filePath)

    $nodes = $toFile.SelectNodes("//package/metadata/dependencies/dependency[starts-with(@id, $packageId)]")
    if ($nodes) {
        foreach ($node in $nodes) {
            $nodeId = $node.id
            Write-Host "-- Updating '$nodeId' in '$filePath' to version '$publishVersion'"
            $node.version = "[" + $publishVersion +"]"
            $toFile.Save($filePath)
        }
   }
}

# Version
$version = "2.0.0.0" 

# Assemblies
$assemblies = "NerveFramework", "NerveFramework.EntityFramework"

# Change dependency version on all depending assemblies
Write-Host "Changing the NuGet Spec version dependencies to '$version'..."
$nuspecFiles = Get-ChildItem $assemblies -Filter "NerveFramework*.nuspec" -Recurse | Resolve-Path -Relative
foreach ($nuspecFile in $nuspecFiles) {
    ChangeNugetSpecDependencyVersion $nuspecFile "NerveFramework" $version
}
```

The error is the `$toFile.Save($filePath)` where it says:

> Exception calling "Save" with "1" argument(s): "En del af stien
>   'C:\Users\Jan\NerveFramework.EntityFramework\NerveFramework.EntityFramework.nuspec'
>   blev ikke fundet." At C:\GitHub\nerve-framework\BuildFunctions.ps1:58
>   char:13
>   +             $toFile.Save($filePath)
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Sorry for the partial danish language, but it says it can not find parts of the path.

One thing here is that this path:  `C:\Users\Jan\NerveFramework.EntityFramework\NerveFramework.EntityFramework.nuspec` is wrong.

The file location is relative to the file executing the command:  `C:\GitHub\nerve-framework\NerveFramework.EntityFramework\NerveFramework.EntityFramework.nuspec`

But it can open the file, but why is the save function then providing the wrong path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `Resolve-Path` at all? You should just pass the full path to the `ChangeNugetSpecDepdencyVersion` function:

Also, within the function, you call `$toFile.Save($filePath)` foreach node - instead of only one time (at the end).

And a last side node: you should use [approved verbs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx) for functions like `Update-NugetSpecDependyVersion` and omit the trailing `()`. Example:

```
Function Update-NugetSpecDependencyVersion 
{
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$filePath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$packageId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$publishVersion
    )

    [xml] $toFile = (Get-Content $filePath)

    $nodes = $toFile.SelectNodes("//package/metadata/dependencies/dependency[starts-with(@id, $packageId)]")
    foreach ($node in $nodes) 
    {
        Write-Host ("-- Updating '{0}' in '{1}' to version '{2}'" -f $node.id, $filePath, $publishVersion)
        $node.version = "[{0}]" -f $publishVersion
    }

    $toFile.Save($filePath)

}

# Version
$version = "2.0.0.0" 

# Assemblies
$assemblies = "NerveFramework", "NerveFramework.EntityFramework"

# Change dependency version on all depending assemblies
Write-Host "Changing the NuGet Spec version dependencies to '$version'..."
Get-ChildItem $assemblies -Filter "NerveFramework*.nuspec" -Recurse | 
        % { Update-NugetSpecDependencyVersion $_.FullName "NerveFramework" $version }
```

Comment: With that I get this error: https://gist.github.com/janhartmann/0b1de4d49b5859e794ed

Comment: Great stuff, works now - going to rewrite my other functions to use same syntax. Thanks man!

Comment: Your welcome! You should also try to minimize Write-Host ;-)

Comment: How come? I need some output for the console window? :-)